# What is "ALL ALL=!SUDOSUDO" for?

Tags: sudo

The last line of the /etc/sudoers file is:

```
grep -i sudosudo /etc/sudoers
Cmnd_Alias SUDOSUDO = /usr/bin/sudo
ALL ALL=!SUDOSUDO
```

why? What does it exactly do?

UPDATE#1: Now I know that it prevents users to use the: "/usr/bin/sudo".

UPDATE#2: not allowing "root ALL=(ALL) ALL" is not a solution.

**Updated Question:** What is better besides this "SUDOSUDO"? (the problem with this that the sudo binary could be copied..)

Comment: `SUDOSUDO` is probably an alias. Does it exist elsewhere in the file?

Comment: question updated :D - so what does it means exactly?

Comment: is "ALL ALL=!SUDOSUDO" as the last line is like when having DROP iptables POLICY and still using a -j DROP rule as last rule in ex.: INPUT chain? :D or does it has real effects?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it only prevents anyone from running `sudo sudo ...`.

Answer (score 4):

That is to prevent someone from running sudo sudo, but it's not very effective.

It is easily circumvented by copying the sudo binary to another
location. for example: cp /bin/sudo /sbin/sudo; sudo /sbin/sudo su -.

Best thing to do is not allowing "root ALL=(ALL) ALL"

Comment: Why would somebody want to disallow running `sudo` with `sudo`?

Comment: Why would you run `sudo sudo`?